# How to stop a form submitting if multiple regular expressions are not matched

Tags: javascript

I want to submit a form that checks two regular expressions.
However, when i use:

```
<input id = "submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateCode(postalCode); return validateCard(cardNumber)" />
```

I only seem to be able to check agains the postal code (and then return to the page), it wont check the card number at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for the VERY simple solution, you could use:

```
onclick="return (validateCode(postalCode) && validateCard(cardNumber));"
```

Assuming these function return false on an invalid input.

Remember, `return` is the last command to execute, so having two in a row will only execute the first. but you can group their result(s) to make them return a "combined" result.